# How to get method names in a class using REST call?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, selenium-webdriver, testng

I m relatively new to REST. I have the following scenario.

1. Project with Selenium Test cases having multiple @Test methods.
2. Dynamic Web Project with simple Home page with some options.

I need to display the method names from multiple Selenium classes. I need to do this using above Web Project.

Kindly suggest me the ways to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Example code would be good.

Comment: Yes please show some code. And do you need to display the method names or Rest resources url mapping [HATEOAS] in rest response?